# Is merging variables safe against SQL injection?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I have a few user inputs

```
$place = $_POST["errorreport_place"];
$os = $_POST["errorreport_os"];
$browser = $_POST["errorreport_browser"];
$text_user = $_POST["errorreport_text_user"];
$section = $_GET["section"];
```

and a few session-variables which aren't created by the user (they are from the DB)

```
$user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
$username = $_SESSION["username"];
```

Now Im merging all these user-created variables to one text-string

```
$text = "ERROR REPORTED BY $username (ID: $user_id)<br /><br />Place: $place<br />Operating System: $os<br />Browser: $browser<br />Text:<br />$text";
```

And then I insert this data to the database (but with prepared statements)

```
$done = 0;
$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO errorreports (user_id, section, text, done) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$sql->bind_param('issi', $user_id, $section, $text, $done);
$sql->execute();
```

And now my question: Is this method safe against SQL injections (because I didn't prepare each user input seperately?

Comment: You are binding variables per `$sql->bind_param('issi', $user_id, $section, $text, $done);`. The origin and content of each is irrelevant. Binding by itself also doesn't change them. It just ensures their values are transferred separately from the SQL query.

Comment: Probably more fit in code review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ plus, don't leave XSS exploits/injection out of the equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method is safe. Concatenation before insertion, while using prepared statements, doesn't matter. The prepared statement will prepare that entire `$text` value as a whole string for insertion - which is still separate from the query itself.

Answer (score 2):

Your method is safe as you're using Prepared statements. `$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO errorreports (user_id, section, text, done) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");`

SQL Injections can occur when you mix data with query. Prepared statements ensure that query and data are sent separately to the server